# What's the name of the default screencast video recording app in Ubuntu 20.04 that starts by pressing ctrl+alt+shift+R?

Tags: desktop-recording

As the title says. I cannot find in the All Apps menu. What is the name of the binary that records the screen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's built in to GNOME Shell.